# How do I set up proxy authentication for the entire system without rooting my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, proxy

I have the Samsung Galaxy S Advance running Android 2.3.6

I was able to set up the proxy server through Settings » Wireless and Network » WiFi Settings » (Options button) » Advanced.

This works well for the browser. If the proxy server requires authentication, then a dialog box pops up for that purpose.

However, all the other apps are totally useless behind a proxy server that requires authentication.

1. How do I work around this without rooting my phone?
2. If rooting is absolutely necessary, what app do you recommend to use (after rooting)? My google searches turn up ProxyDroid. Are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

The app that did the trick for me is [Auto Proxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gpc.myweb.hinet.net.AutoProxy) (requires root).

All apps work, including browser, maps, GMail, etc. and it worked on Android 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0.

Additionally, WiFi proxy settings are built in to ICS, but I've had limited success with it. It seems to automatically disconnect from the wireless network. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273) on the android site for this which is still open. You can set proxy settings for APN (Mobile Network) but not for Wifi. 
In ICS also only the Browser will be affected by the Wifi Proxy Setting.

Also Authentification will not completly work at all (see report)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Droxy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sandroproxy.drony&hl=en) (no root required)

Before opening Drony, change the hostname and port in Wi-Fi settings(modify network), to hostname: localhost port: `8080`, the open Drony, and put in your actual wi-fi proxy hostname, port, username, and password.

Comment: Please post a link?